# Everything opens dolphin file manager windows

Tags: file-association, filemanager

Every kind of file I open through ubuntu dash or via firefox download window instead of directly open the right application it launches a dolphin window straight to the path of the file and just then the default application is opened.

This is very annoying so I decided to unistall dolphin and now when i try to open a file in dash or firefox i got this message "Failed to execute child process "dolphin" (No such file or directory)."

I hope i was clear enough as english is not my primary language.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options->Applications in Firefox to manage how files you download in Firefox are handled. What you're looking for may also be in Tools->Options->General.

Comment: Everything looks fine in firefox files associations.

Comment: Have you looked at the "System Info->Default Applications" settings under the "System Settings" application?

Comment: The `Applications` menu (which is actually inside `Edit->Preferences`) affects what Firefox does *before* downloading. It defines whether a `pdf` should be opened with evince, or just downloaded, or opened with okular. Once a file has *already* been downloaded, you can manually open it from the "Downloads" window. That's what the question was about and the settings in the `Applications` menu have no influence on that.